# OpenCV background subtraction learning rate cannot change

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I wish to train a background region with 50 frames and use this pre-trained model for background subtraction. Model stops updating after training.

Here is my code

```
import cv2
print "This program is for background subtraction with pre-trained model\n"

Training_Floder = "/Users/yuyang/Desktop/img1/"
Start_Frame_Num = 1
End_Frame_Num = 51

cv2.namedWindow("BG_IMAGE")

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(50, 16, False)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX



for index in range(Start_Frame_Num, End_Frame_Num):
    Img_File_Name = Training_Floder + str(index) + ".jpg"
    Img = cv2.imread(Img_File_Name)
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(Img, -1)
    BG_IMG = fgbg.getBackgroundImage()
    #######
    cv2.putText(BG_IMG,str(index),(10,500), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)
    cv2.imshow("BG_IMAGE", BG_IMG)
    #######
    cv2.waitKey(0)

Testing_Floder = "/Users/yuyang/Desktop/New/"
Test_Start = 1
Test_End = 100

for index in range(Test_Start, Test_End):
    Img_File_Name = Testing_Floder + str(index) + ".jpg"
    Img = cv2.imread(Img_File_Name)
    fgmask1 = fgbg.apply(Img, 0)
    BG_IMG1 = fgbg.getBackgroundImage()
    cv2.putText(BG_IMG1,str(index),(10,500), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)
    cv2.imshow("BG_IMAGE", BG_IMG1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Based on the comments

The learning rate parameter is in the function "apply()".

```
@param learningRate 
The value between 0 and 1 that indicates how fast the background 
model is learnt. Negative parameter value makes the algorithm to 
use some automatically chosen learning rate. 0 means that the 
background model is not updated at all, 1 means that the background 
model is completely reinitialized from the last frame.

CV_WRAP virtual void apply(InputArray image, OutputArray fgmask, double learningRate=-1) = 0;"
```

However, I tried several learning rate here:

```
fgmask = fgbg.apply(Img, -1) or
fgmask = fgbg.apply(Img, 0) or
fgmask = fgbg.apply(Img, 1) or
fgmask = fgbg.apply(Img, 0.00001)
```

The training Background result does not change.
This means I CANNOT keep pre-trained model unchanged while testing!

Is there anything wrong with my code?
Is there any way to change the learning rate?

Here are some results

[Background subtraction result of Testing image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oeiy7.jpg)

[Background subtraction result of Testing image #40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3erO.jpg)

From the result above, it is clear that the trained background image changes while testing, although I set learning rate as 0.

```
fgmask1 = fgbg.apply(Img, 0)
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. When you say ```model stops updating after training```, the model is actually supposed to stop updating after the training is over. And, what is the problem with your learning rate? Is it changing during training after some iterations or not? Please be more explicit. First state the question heading clearly and make sure the rest of the question is coherent and in sync with the heading.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 
During training, I set learning rate as -1. This is a default value. And I plan  to apply pre-trained model on testing frames. And this time I set the training rate as 0 ------"0 means that the background model is not updated at all". However, the background model is still updating with training rate 0. I tested this on both opencv c++ sample code and my own python code. I am not sure it is my coding problem or opencv BUG

Comment: If the #frames for training is T, set learning rate -1 is to set learning rate as 1/T

Comment: As far as I understand training and testing codes should be separate. Though testing can be done during training, you should not have any code for training as you already have a pretrained model. Just remove the training part and retain only the testing part.

Comment: I update the code and added the trained background image. the model changes while training

Comment: Can you remove the training code and keep only the testing part?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem~~

Comment: Are you familiar with GMM based background subtraction?

Comment: I agree with you @YangYu this is an annoying problem, model keeps updating even with learning rate 0...

Comment: @Curious This problem was solved, the I made a mistake of the python version of function fgbg.apply(). I didn't change learning rate by just using "fgmask = fgbg.apply(Img, Learning_Rate)", because Learning rate here is the 2nd parameter, but actually, it is the 3rd. I forgot the details. I thought the python function parameter is very similar with cpp version

Answer (score 4):

So the correct way to use the python implementation is

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(50, 16, False)
fgbg.apply(input, output, learning_rate)
```

Exactly as in the c++ implementation.
The learning rate must be the third parameter.

Comment: Desired behavior is given as follows: `output = fgbg.apply(input, None, learning_rate)`