# Opencv 3.4.4 createBackgroundSubtractorKNN learning rate won't work

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm using OpenCV 3.4.4 on raspberry pi and I want to perform BackgroundSubtractorKNN on a streaming video. I use the first 300 frames as background, with a learning_rate = 1 and then I would like to use this model to find my object. For this reason I set my learning_rate = 0, but the model continues to learn and if the object remains stable it disappear completely.

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(history=history,detectShadows=True)
inc=0
while inc<300
  frame = cap.read()
  fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame,1)
  #fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask, -1) # I used also this method but won't work
  inc +=1

while True
  frame = cap.read()
  fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame,0)
  #fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask, 0) # I used also this method but won't work
  cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
```

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358155/opencv-background-subtraction-learning-rate-cannot-change) and I tried to apply the solution, but it is not effective. Is it a bug? Because I have another Raspberry pi with installed opencv 3.1 and this code works perfectly.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same problem, and therefore I believe it is a bug. I've tried swapping out `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` instead of `createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()` and that one does behave as expected.

Comment: Yes, a the end I gave up and I did exactly the same thing.